# Authentication on Rails w/ Authlogic not working with Chome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, authentication

I have a Rails 3.0 application with the latest version of Authlogic. The user login works as expected on localhost. It works in production when using Safari or Firefox or Chrome in incognito mode, but it does not work when using Chrome normally. I have a Resque interface hooked up in the `config.ru`, but turning it on or off does not make a difference.

It does work when `allow_http_basic_auth` is set to false, but I need this to be enabled because our API makes use of basic auth.

Anyone else have a similar issue or any idea what could be causing this to happen?

UPDATE:

So I can login in Chrome using http_basic by typing the full URL (e.g. https://user:pass@site.com).

The cookie is the same in Chrome (when not able to log in) as it is in Safari.

It look like what is happening is that the user actually gets logged in, then redirect to a different page (302). This page then thinks that the user is not logged in and the user then gets redirected to the login page.